# SKShapeNode stroke not drawing in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, stroke, skshapenode

I have this code:

```
    self.shapeNode = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(origin: CGPointMake(-0.5*size.width, -0.5*size.height), size: size))
    self.shapeNode.fillColor = UIColor.lightBlueColor()
    self.shapeNode.strokeColor = UIColor.brownColor()
```

The shapeNode appears and its fill color is drawn, though its stroke isn't. Back in iOS 7 in Obj-C, the same code works to draw the stroke.

Comment: try setting the lineWidth explicitly

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I did try that, though it didn't work. Some people suggest that this is a bug in the iOS Simulator. I can't test on a device yet because I'm not on iOS 8 yet. I'll just have to trust them for now unless something turns up. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I get the same thing in the simulator. Stroke appears as normal on the device but not in the simulator. Fill appears on both. I'm using a path to draw lines though, so it must be an SKShapeNode issue.

Comment: I have this same issue, it's extremely annoying since I have no way of simulating this in the iPhone 6 resolutions to capture screenshots. Also I use shadows with iOS 8 so I can't default to iOS 7 and capture the shape strokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this turned out to be just a bug in the simulator. Yesterday, I installed the public version of iOS 8 on an iPad, ran my game on it and the strokes appeared. Apple should provide a fix for this soon, though.

Comment: It's a bug indeed. I have the same problem: lines are show on the iPad but not on the simulator.

Comment: This same bug is still present in the simulator for iOS 9 on XCode 7.